# NullPointerException when scrolling ListView with images loaded from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, listview, nullpointerexception

I've an error, when using ListView in Android, which is populated with images. Images urls are from tumblr JSON and android query loads them. Error message which I get is:

```
12-12 21:55:38.032    4334-4334/com.example.tumblrviewer E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
12-12 21:55:38.040    4334-4334/com.example.tumblrviewer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 760K, 12% free 9993K/11292K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
12-12 21:55:38.040    4334-4334/com.example.tumblrviewer E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.tumblrviewer.MenuArrayAdapter.getView(MenuArrayAdapter.java:76)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2161)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:639)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4970)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onGenericMotionEvent(AbsListView.java:3680)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEventInternal(View.java:7479)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7460)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1819)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1772)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7453)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1819)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1772)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7453)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1819)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1772)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7453)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1819)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1772)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7453)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1974)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1428)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:2460)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1928)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7566)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 21:55:38.044    4334-4334/com.example.tumblrviewer D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-12 21:55:38.044    4334-4334/com.example.tumblrviewer W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bd3648)
12-12 21:55:38.052    4334-4334/com.example.tumblrviewer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.tumblrviewer.MenuArrayAdapter.getView(MenuArrayAdapter.java:76)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2161)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:639)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4970)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onGenericMotionEvent(AbsListView.java:3680)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEventInternal(View.java:7479)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7460)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1819)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1772)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7453)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1819)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1772)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7453)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1819)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1772)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7453)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1819)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1772)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7453)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1974)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1428)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:2460)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1928)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7566)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it points to MenuArrayAdapter line 76, which contains:

```
        mAQ.id(viewHolder.mImageView).image(item.photos[0].photoUrl.uri, false, false, 600, 0, null, Constants.FADE_IN);
```

and I'm pretty sure this object is not null, because error occurs random, each time with different item in ArrayAdapter. It happens when I scroll ListView fast, up and down. I see that images does not have a time to load. Can it be related with a problem with memory? that there is too much data in the memory and app crashes? If so, what would be a good solution, if I want to stay with infinite scroll - I don't want to add "load more" button in the bottom, as e.g. Instagram does not have such button and it can load lots of images.

full code of this class is as follows:

```
package com.example.tumblrviewer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxCallback;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxStatus;
import com.androidquery.util.Constants;
import com.example.tumblrviewer.model.HomeResponse;
import com.example.tumblrviewer.model.Item;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MenuArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final int mResourceId;
private AQuery mAQ;
private int postOffset;
public MenuArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);

    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mResourceId = resource;
    mAQ = new AQuery(context);
    postOffset=0;
   //loadImages(postOffset);
}


public void setPosts(Item[] posts) {

    //clear();

    for (Item item : posts) {

        add(item);
    }

    if (isEmpty()) {
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    } else {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mResourceId, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tumblr_photo_iv);
        //viewHolder.mTagsLayout=(LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tags_layout);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Item item = getItem(i);

   //if ( item.photos[0].photoUrl.uri != null) {
        mAQ.id(viewHolder.mImageView).image(item.photos[0].photoUrl.uri, false, false, 600, 0,  null, Constants.FADE_IN);
   //}

    return convertView;


}


private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImageView;
    //LinearLayout mTagsLayout;

}
}
```

There is also main activity

```
package com.example.tumblrviewer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxCallback;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxStatus;
import com.example.tumblrviewer.model.HomeResponse;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class WeHaveTheMunchiesActivity extends Activity {

private AQuery mAQ;
private TextView mResultTextView;
private ListView mListView;
private MenuArrayAdapter mItemArrayAdapter;
private int postOffset;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_viewer);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.items_lv);
    mAQ = new AQuery(this);
    mItemArrayAdapter = new MenuArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_on_list);
    mListView.setAdapter(mItemArrayAdapter);
    postOffset=0;
    loadImages(postOffset);



    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


            int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if(lastItem == totalItemCount ){

                if(postOffset <= 10662
                        && mListView.getChildAt(mListView.getChildCount() - 1) != null
                        && mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() == mListView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                        && mListView.getChildAt(mListView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= mListView.getHeight()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bottom!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loadImages(postOffset);
                    System.out.println("postOffset "+postOffset);

                }
            }
        }
    });

}


private void loadImages(int offset) {

    String url = Constants.TUMBLR_API_BLOG_URL + Constants.TUMBLR_API_BLOG_HOSTNAME +
            Constants.TUMBLR_API_CONTENT_TYPE + Constants.TUMBLR_API_KEY_NAME +
            Constants.TUMBLR_API_KEY + "&offset=" + Integer.toString(offset);


    AjaxCallback<JSONObject> cb = new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>();
    cb.url(url).type(JSONObject.class).weakHandler(this, "itemsCallback");
    mAQ.ajax(cb);
    postOffset=postOffset+20;


}

public void itemsCallback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) throws JSONException {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status.getRedirect(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //mResultTextView.setText(status.getMessage());
    if (json != null) {
        HomeResponse homeResponse = HomeResponse.fromJsonObject(json.getJSONObject("response"));
        System.out.print(homeResponse.items);
        mItemArrayAdapter.setPosts(homeResponse.items);
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Could be the that it has issues with loading. What about if you'd use AsyncTask to load the images inBackground ?

Comment: Something in there is absolutely null. It could be items, items.photos, items.photos[0], item.photos[0].photoUrl, or the return of maq.id.  Test each of these individually with an if statement and figure out which it is first.  THat makes it easier for us to help and you to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Gabe has it - Your data is null somewhere. Another method to find it is to output the entire JSON string.

Comment: @GabeSechan you were right, I've eliminated such possibility because previously I've added test, where I checked if item.photos[0].photoUrl != null, but it turned out that item.photos was null, because some posts in JSON did not have photos. Now I'm filtering JSON output, selecting only photo posts. Thanks a lot!